# Client does not connect to server over internet

Tags: .net, sockets, tcp, client, ip

I've set up a simple client/server system, but for some reason the client won't connect via the internet. I've got them communicating on the same machine, using both the localhost address (127.0.0.1) and my LAN IP address (192.168.2.2).

I've also confirmed that the port is open using http://www.whatsmyip.org/ports/, and when I use this site, the callback function is triggered on the server, so I assume the server is working properly.

However, when I try to connect to the same (internet) IP address/port from my client, the server detects nothing and the client throws an exception at the OnConnect callback. I've noticed that the RemoteEndPoint property of clientSocket is not being set correctly by the BeginConnect statement - it throws a SocketException (10057) when I look at it. (When connecting via the LAN address, it works fine.)

```
private void ConnectToServer()
{
    clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(txtIPAddress.Text);

    IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, Convert.ToInt32(txtPort.Text));
    clientSocket.BeginConnect(ipEndPoint, new AsyncCallback(OnConnect), null);
}
```

What could stop the client connecting to the server via the external IP address, given that it can connect via the LAN IP address and that the server is accepting connections over the internet?

I'm using Windows 7 and .NET 3.0.

Any advice gratefully appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked your filewall settings? Ensure the port is open to incoming connections.

Comment: If you can connect via some IP addresses and not others, it's not really a programming question.

Comment: Yes, the port is open. See paragraph 2 above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you should not expect the socket to be connected right after you have called `BeginConnect`. It usually takes a few round-trips to establish a connection. So an error code of `10057 Not Connected` is expected when asking about the remote endpoint before the connection has been established.

As to why your network set-up does not work. If I understand your set-up correctly, you are trying to send packets in the following manner:

```
Your machine (LAN) --> Port-forwarding device (WAN) --> Your machine (LAN)
```

Have you verified that the port-forwarding device supports this set-up?

You state that you have verified the following:

```
Remote machine (WAN) --> Port-forwarding device (WAN) --> Your machine (LAN)
```

Your port-forwarding device may lack support for `LAN -> WAN -> LAN` port-forwarding.

You may also want to use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to see what packets are sent.

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't considered that LAN -> WAN -> LAN forwarding could be any different to WAN -> WAN -> LAN forwarding. I'll try to investigate this. My setup, for reference, is a gateway router (set as DMZ) and a wireless router (forwarding on the specified port only) so I guess either of them could be the problem?

Regarding BeginConnect, when you say it takes a few round-trips, you mean it just takes time? I stopped the program with the debugger to check the values - it didn't change no matter how long I waited.

Comment: Yes, the round-trip-time is the time it takes for the client to send a packet to the server until it receives a response from the server. You should also see `10060 Connection Timed Out` as an error code after a few minutes, but using a debugger may change this.

Comment: Your suggestion seems to be correct, as I installed the client software on a machine with a separate internet connection and it worked fine.
I don't really understand why the router should fail to forward requests from its own LAN and I couldn't figure out how to change it, but at least now I can test my programs using the LAN IP address, and still expect them to work over the internet after distribution. Thanks for your help, Mats.